# Randomize an array of team names and return n number of teams

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, random, split

I've been struggling for HOURS on how to create a function that takes an array of names and divides them into *n* number of teams, with all the names in the teams being random.

I could do something like:

```
var numBig = size of the array % number of teams

var smallTeamSize = Math.floor(size of the array % number of teams)
```

The largest of the teams should have only one more name than the rest of the teams.

So first `numBig` teams would have `smallTeamSize + 1` names and the remaining teams will have `smallTeamSize` names.

The inputs and outputs should look like this:

`function randTeams(array, 3);`

Then the function might (because it's random) print out the following:

```
Team 1: jimes, jim, joe
Team 2: jake, rob
Team 3: paps, richie
```

Any suggestions?

I have a function that randomizes an array of names:

```
var array = ['jim','jake','jimes','rob','paps','richie','joe'];

function shuffleArray(array) {

    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}

var newarray =(shuffleArray(array));
```

How would I take newarray and make it into smaller teams?

Comment: Divide your task into subtasks and work on them separately.

Comment: Can you add an example of input and a valid output?

Comment: You want to pass an array of names, and have the function return two arrays, one for each team of players?

Comment: Sorry, I just added what the inputs and outputs should look like

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this on the assumption you want to take an array of names, and from those names create two teams (though that's clearly not explicit in your question):

```
function createTeams(names) {
    var team1 = [],
        n;
    for (var i = 0, len = Math.floor(names.length / 2); i < len; i++) {
        n = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
        team1.push(names[n]);
        names.splice(n, 1);
    }
    return {
        'team1': team1,
            'team2': names
    };
}

var teams = createTeams(['James', 'Bill', 'William', 'Jack', 'Steve']),
    team1 = teams.team1,
    team2 = teams.team2;

console.log(team1, team2); // ["Steve", "William"] ["James", "Bill", "Jack"]
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XU5zr/1/).

Edited, to include a somewhat messy means of creating arbitrary numbers of teams:

```
function createTeams(names, numTeams) {
    if (!names || typeof names == 'number'){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        numTeams = typeof numTeams == 'undefined' ? 2 : Math.abs(parseInt(numTeams,10));
        var teams = {},
            perTeam = Math.floor(names.length/numTeams),
            n;
        for (var i = 0; i < numTeams; i++){
            teams[i] = [];
        }
        while (names.length - perTeam > 0){
            for (var i = 0; i < numTeams; i++){
                n = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
                if (names.length >= 0 && typeof names[n] !== 'undefined'){
                    teams[i].push(names[n]);
                    names.splice(n,1);
                }
            }
        }
        return teams;
    }
}

var teams = createTeams(['James', 'Bill', 'William', 'Jack', 'Steve'], '5');

console.log(teams);

/*
    {
        '0' : ['Steve'],
        '1' : ['James'],
        '2' : ['Bill'],
        '3' : ['Jack'],
        '4' : ['William']
    }
*/
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XU5zr/2/).

References:

- [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).
- [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).
- [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

Comment: So this divides my array into two teams. How would you do it so that you could specify how many teams you want?

Comment: I'm not sure your second function works. If I pass 9 names into it, with 4 teams as the params, it gives me 4 teams of 2 with 1 person missing

Answer (score 0):

you can add function splitTeams to your shuffleArray

```
function splitTeams(names) {
    return {'team1': names.splice(0, Math.floor(names.length/2)),
        'team2': names}
}
```

and use it like this

```
var teams = splitTeams(shuffleArray(['jim','jake','jimes','rob','paps','richie']))
```

to make several teams you can use this variant of splitTeams:

```
function splitTeams(names, teams_count) {
    var teams = [];
    while (teams_count > 0) {
    teams.push(names.splice(0, Math.floor(names.length/teams_count)))
    teams_count--;
    }
    return teams
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your randomized array, it's easy to "deal the players out" to whatever number you want:

```
function distributePlayers(names, numberOfTeams) {
    var ret = {};
    var teamCounter = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
        if (!ret["array" + teamCounter]) {
            ret["array" + teamCounter] = [];
        }
        ret["array" + teamCounter].push(names[i]);
        if (++teamCounter == numberOfTeams) {
            teamCounter = 0;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Then all you need is:

```
var newArray = shuffleArray(array);
var arrays = distributePlayers(newArray, numberOfTeams);
```

Inside `arrays` will be members array1, array2 ... arrayN.

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZHjA/)

**Update**:

To iterate through the return, iterate through all of the object's own properties, and in each one, join the array to get the full team:

```
for (var property in arrays) {
    // check to make sure you didn't stumble on an inherited property
    if (arrays.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        var str = property + ": " + arrays[property].join(", ");
        console.log(str);
    }
}
```

This will produce the output:

```
array0: richie, jimes, rob
array1: joe, jim
array2: paps, jake
```

If you want to rename the arrays to reflect the team name, just change the `if` inside the `for` loop in `distributePlayers`:

```
if (!ret["Team" + (teamCounter + 1)) {
    ret["Team" + (teamCounter + 1));
}
ret["Team" + (teamCounter + 1)].push(names[i]);
```

This way, your array name will actually reflect useful information.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZHjA/1/)

Comment: Okay, so this returns an object that has multiple array attributes and then returns that object. How could I make it go through and print out each array attribute? 

So the output looks like
`Team 1: jimes, jim, joe`
`Team 2: jake, rob`
`Team 3: paps, richie`

Answer (score 0):

see this code which shuffles array and slices it

```
var names = ['jim','jake','jimes','rob','paps','richie'];
names.sort(function(){
    return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
});
var noOfTeams = 3;
var totalTeams = Math.ceil(names.length/noOfTeams);  

var i,j,temparray,chunk = totalTeams;
for (i=0,j=names.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
    temparray = names.slice(i,i+chunk);
    console.log(temparray);
}
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abhiklpm/QDF5J/ , in console you will see the random arrays